# Trying to use CoffeeScript with JQuery, I get a "document is not defined" error

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I start like I usually do in javascript, so:

```
$(document).ready ->
```

but when I save I get a document is not defined. So far I haven't been able to find how to make it work.

Edit: by save, I meant I was using coffee -w. The error was due to me forgetting to use the -c option.

Comment: You are compiling the CoffeeScript to JavaScript, right?

Comment: actually, that was the mistake. I added the -c to the commandline and it worked.

Comment: sidenote: you can collapse that statement into `$ ->`

Answer (score 18):

CoffeeScript is compiled into JavaScript. I'm not sure what you're trying, but in your exact case your CoffeeScript isn't going to look a whole lot different than your JavaScript. Try:

```
$(document).ready -> alert 'blah'
```

If that doesn't work, just do a test like

```
alert document.title
```

if that doesn't work, I'm going to suggest that you're not running this code inside a browser ;)

Comment: thanks for this, it allowed me to see where I was wrong and it's pretty stupid. Apparently, I wasn't trying to actually compile the code, just to run it, since I had forgot to throw in the -c option, now everything is working :)